# Encoding numbers with relationship into one and back

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, it.information-theory

Given a set of many variables $S=\{x_1,x_2, ...., x_i\}$, and any subset $S'$ of $S$, I need a function $f$ which maps $S'$ to a value $x$ and a function $f'$ which maps $x$ back to set $S'$.

I know my question can be solved with [Gödel_numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), but it will consume a lot of space and the computation cost is quite high when the size of $S'$ is big.

Is there any relationship the values in $S$ can satisfy such that we can make function $f$ and $f'$ very easy?

I tried making all values in S to be even, odd or prime and function f as sum. But it clearly does not work.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question as this one on [math.se]: [How to encode many integer easily](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3911141). If you look at the recommendations related to [meta-tag:cross-posting], you should probably indicate that you have posted to both sites. See, for example: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. I was about to say this. I know there is a similar question link posted many years ago. But my case is different, I allow values in S to satisfy some requirements or relationship. I hope that it could make the problem easier.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your suggestions. I have deleted my old question posted in MATH SE.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, a comment linking to this question was posted here before: [Encoding $n$ natural numbers into one and back](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69244). It seems that it was deleted for some reason.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I post this question after I have look at the question you link to in your comments. The solution for that question is still very costly.  I allow values in S to satisfy some requirements or relationship. I hope that it could make the problem easier.

Comment: You can use a hash table with an appropriate hash function. You may be able to somehow alter the hash function depending on the relationship you have between the elements

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Without more details, this seems too general to be appropriate for MO.  For general answers, such as @ogogmad's above, this would probably be better suited for MSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is inspired by answers in the other linked threads. You can let $f(S') = \sum_{x_j \in S'} 2^{j-1}$.

If you let your set only contain powers of 2, i.e. $S = \{ 1, 2, 4, 8, \ldots , 2^i\}$, then $f(S') = \sum_{x_j \in S'} x_j$, the sum of all numbers in $S'$.

Note that this is the same as interpreting $S'$ as a length $i$ binary number where the $j$th bit is 1 if $x_j \in S'$ and 0 otherwise. Note that there are $2^i$ different subsets of $S$ so you need a binary number of length at least $i$ to be able to represent all possible subsets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function is quite simple. The only issue is the length of bits increases linearly with the size of S'. Can we find a good way to reduce the memory cost (e.g., increasing sub-linearly)?

Comment: Another possible issue is that the number will goes very big such that 64 bits machine cannot represent when the size of S is large.

Comment: There are $2^{|S|}$ different subsets of $S$ so you need an $|S|$-bit number to be able to identify all possible subsets.